# Check if Read-Host is a number for Switch

Tags: powershell

I'm just learning `switch` to make my logic a bit cleaner, and it seems to work except I'm having trouble determining if my `Read-Host` value is a number (for the access point number to select).

```
     ## Give option to reset all aps on site
    $continueVal = Read-Host "`nSpecify AP # to see more details or type 'Reset' to reset all APs in Store $Store"
```

## Start switch

```
$event = switch ($continueVal) {
    [int]{
        $apNumber = $continueVal
        Query-AP($apNumber)
    }
    'Reset' {
        Manage-Prelim($e = 2)
    }
    default {
        Repeat
    }
}
```

When I was using `If/Else/ElseIf` I'd use `if($continueVal -gt 0)` which would work, but still dirty. With `switch` it seems that `-gt 0` is improper syntax and fails. How would I effectively check if the value of `$continueVal` is a number to pass it to the next function as `$apNumber`?

I don't want to pre-validate as possible options can come through as an integer or a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach that uses parameters and parameter sets:

```
# testscript.ps1
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = "APNumber")]
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,ParameterSetName = "APNumber")]
  [Int] $APNumber,

  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,ParameterSetName = "Controller")]
  [String] $Controller,

  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,ParameterSetName = "Reset")]
  [Switch] $Reset
)

switch ( $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName ) {
  "APNumber" {
    "You specified -APNumber with value '$APNumber'"
    break
  }
  "Controller" {
    "You specified -Controller with value '$Controller'"
    break
  }
  "Reset" {
    "You specified -Reset"
    break
  }
}
```

This script is simple to use. Example usage:

```
testscript -APNumber 3
testscript -Controller "foo"
testscript -Reset
```

If you omit any parameters, it will prompt for the `-APNumber` parameter (since it specifies that as the default parameter set).

Answer (score 1):

Now that I understand your question more, this can be done with `switch -regex` and parsing. Here is a short example:

```
do {
  $response = Read-Host "Enter a response"
  $valid = $true
  switch -regex ( $response ) {
    '^AP Number \d+$' {
      $arg = [Regex]::Match($_,'\d+$').Value -as [Int]
      Write-Host "You entered 'AP Number $arg'"
      break
    }
    '^Controller \S+$' {
      $arg = [Regex]::Match($_,'\S+$').Value
      Write-Host "You entered 'Controller $arg'"
      break
    }
    '^Reset$' {
      Write-Host "You entered 'Reset'"
      break
    }
    default {
      $valid = $false
      Write-Host "Invalid entry"
    }
  }
}
until ( $valid )
```

Note that this is more code than the parameter version, more complex, and you can't automate it.

Comment: I do know this for standard validation, but this is in regards to using ```switch``` as there are 4 possibilities.

Comment: Combine the concepts. See updated answer with an example that uses `switch`.

Comment: Okay, so I should be more clear with the code block I've given. I don't need to validate that it is always a number, because it won't always be number. Possibilities are ```AP Number [int]```,```"Reset"[string]```,```Controller[string]```, or ```"Exit"[string]```. So that being said, that's what has me confused, because any of these concepts that I stitch together don't seem to have the outcome I'm shooting for.

Comment: My code is easily extended to do that, but I think you would be better served by redesigning your script to use parameters and parameter sets rather than interactive user input.

Comment: Using parameters and parameter sets will be a much more flexible approach and can also be automated. Start by reading the PowerShell help topics: `help about_Functions` and `help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters`. I strongly recommend learning more about parameters before proceeding with your interactive input design.

Comment: My intent is not to antagonize but rather to point out that there is a better way to do what you are asking. See my other answer.

Comment: I understand. I appreciate your help! Considering the use case, I'm going to avoid parameters as the users will be keeping this tool open at all times not running it from command line. If this isn't possible using switch, I'll just keep my working elseifs.

Comment: @CodeSpent - I replaced this answer with an update. Perhaps this is more like what you want to do? (Though I still recommend the script with parameters, as it is more PowerShell-like, easier to read, and can be automated.)